# copying files from one folder to another folder based on the file names in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, copy

In Python 3.7, I want to write a scrip that

- creates folders based on a list
- iterates through a list (elements represent different "runs")
- searches for .txt files in predifined directories derived from certain operations
- copies certain .txt files to the previously created folders

I managed to do that via following script:

```
from shutil import copy
import os
import glob

# define folders and batches
folders = ['folder_ce', 'folder_se']
runs = ['A001', 'A002', 'A003']

# make folders 
for f in folders:
    os.mkdir(f)

# iterate through batches,
# extract files for every operation,
# and copy them to target folder
for r in runs:
    # operation 1
    ce = glob.glob(f'{r}/{r}/several/more/folders/{r}*.txt')
    for c in ce:
        copy(c, 'folder_ce')

    # operation 2
    se = glob.glob(f'{r}/{r}/several/other/folders/{r}*.txt')
    for s in se:
        copy(s, 'folder_se')
```

In the predifined directories there are several .txt files

- one file with the format A001.txt (where the "A001"-part is derived from the list "runs" specified above)
- plus sometimes several files with the format A001.20200624.1354.56.txt

If a file with the format A001.txt is there, I only want to copy this one to the target directory.
If the format A001.txt is not available, I want to copy **all** files with the longer format (e.g. A001.20200624.1354.56.txt).

After the comment of @adamkwm, I tried

```
if f'{b}/{b}/pcs.target/data/xmanager/CEPA_Station/Verwaltung_CEPA_44S4/{b}.txt' in cepa:
    copy(f'{b}/{b}/pcs.target/data/xmanager/CEPA_Station/Verwaltung_CEPA_44S4/{b}.txt', 'c_py_1')
else:
    for c in cepa:
        copy(c, 'c_py_1')
```

but that still copies both files (A001.txt and A001.20200624.1354.56.txt), which I understand. I think the trick is to first check in ce, which is a list, if the {r}.txt format is present and if it is, only copy that one. If not, copy all files. However, I don't seem to get the logic right or use the wrong modules or methods, it seems.

After searching for answers, i didn't find one resolving this specific case.
Can you help me with a solution for this "selective copying" of the files?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe something like `if f'{r}.txt' in ce: copy(f'{r}.txt', 'folder_ce') else: for ...`

Comment: thanks @adamkwm, I already tried
`if f'{r}/{r}/several/more/folders/{r}.txt' in ce: copy(f'{r}/{r}/several/more/folders/{r}.txt', 'folder_ce') else: for c in ce: copy(c, 'folder_ce')`

but that still copies both files (A001.txt and A001.20200624.1354.56.txt), which I understand.
I think the trick is to first check in ce, which is a list, if the {r}.txt format is present and if it is, only copy that one.
if not, copy all files.
However, I don't seem to get the logic right or use the wrong modules or methods, it seems.
Any ideas on that?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what's going on. I'm not familiar working with files and I just guess the if else statement will work in this case. It works for me in my little test, but not sure if it works in any case or are there better ways to doing this.